# Neo4j Java API: GC overhead limit exceeded after running multiple queries

Tags: java, neo4j, garbage-collection, graph-databases

I’m using *Neo4j 2.3.0* in *Java*. I have 16 GB RAM, running the code on MAC OSX Laptop, using "**-Xmx12g -Xms12g**" as VM arguments.

I’ve encountered a “GC overhead limit exceeded” problem in Neo4j Java API.

In order to do experiments with lots of queries, I have a program which opens a transaction over different query.db's and get the answers of that from my own framework which is wrapped in an object (It runs a query and print its running time in a file).

So, for running the query, I don’t use **Cypher**.

For each query I open **two transactions** over a query.db and a data.db, initialize my framework and run it. The memory usage slightly increases and the “GC overhead” finally happens.

```
try (Transaction txG = knowledgeGraph.beginTx()) {
     try (Transaction txQ = queryGraph.beginTx()) {
          MyObj myFramework = new MyObj();
          printTheResultsIntoTheFile(framework.run());
          myFramework =null;
          txQ.success();
          txQ.close();
```

**These are some of my endeavors to get rid of this error:**

1. After I’ve used a monitoring program to dump the heap, I’ve found that there is some problem with this “**org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache**”
   So, I’ve tried to set the page cache size and limit it to a small value:

   `dataGraph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(MODELGRAPH_DB_PATH)
       .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "500M").newGraphDatabase();`

However, still the "memory leakage” problem exists.

2. After `tx.success()`, I called the `tx.close()` to make sure that it doesn’t use the memory.
3. After using my framework(object) to find the answers of a query, I explicitly set it to null. `topkFramework=null;`
4. I called `System.gc();` and `System.runFinalization();`
5. I changed all of my static variables like MyCacheServer or MyNeighborIndexer to non-static ones and in each query, I made them clear, and explicitly set them to null.

   `queryNodeIdSet.clear();
   queryNodeIdSet = null;
   queryNodeIdSet = new HashSet<Long>();`

Comment: Could you find a way to share your heap dump with us, or at least the biggest memory users? Which tool did you use? You needn't bother setting things to null, calling gc(), finalizers etc.

Comment: I've used MemoryAnalyzer for eclipse. The biggest object is org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPage which got 3.54 GB of memory. Other objects is ok in my case because of some indexing.

Comment: OK, I know MAT well, but it'll be very hard to diagnose this way. Have you tried the dominator view rather than the histogram, and tried to work down to the GC roots so you can see what's keeping all those objects alive?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how I can increase its heap size. Denominator tree generation gave me the heap size error for MAT. Could you please guide me how I can increase heap space for that program in MAC OSX?

Comment: Luckily I am also an OS X user. Edit `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` in the same dir. I have `-vmargs` on line 1, `-Xmx3g` on line 2.

Comment: The root cause is that the code creates hundreds of Neo4j instances each with a full config, and then doesn't clearly shuts them down. And that off-heap page-cache is only released at JVM shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you only use one Neo4j instance per JVM instance.

The off-heap page-cache is unfortunately not released until the JVM shuts down.

And for the heap related sections you will have to **make sure** that `shutdown` is called and also null-out references before calling `System.gc()`

You can just reuse your "smallGraph", clean out the instance, e.g. with `MATCH (n) DETACH DELETE n;` And then repopulate it.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of digging into Neo4j, I've found that it's related to create a lot of query graphs one after one. Although I called db.shutdown() after my work with each query, it seems that cache won't be empty.

```
smallGraph = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(graphPath)
            .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.pagecache_memory, "240k").newGraphDatabase();
```

I've added this config and set it to minimum possible amount. Right now the memory leakage is not too much to break my process. After running around 1000 queries it's still running. Earlier it consumed all of my memory (12 GB) after running 200 queries.

This was my stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

    at org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.muninn.MuninnPageCache.<init>(MuninnPageCache.java:246)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.createPageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:96)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.pagecache.ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.getOrCreatePageCache(ConfiguringPageCacheFactory.java:87)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.createPageCache(PlatformModule.java:277)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.PlatformModule.<init>(PlatformModule.java:154)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.createPlatform(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:181)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:124)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.CommunityFacadeFactory.newFacade(CommunityFacadeFactory.java:43)

    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:108)

    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:129)

    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:117)

    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:185)

    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:79)

    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:74)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess (no time to try it now), but I'll give it a go. Neo4j doesn't support nested transactions. Any top-level transaction (`txG` in your case) is bound to `ThreadLocal`. Any "nested" transaction (`txQ`) becomes a `PlaceboTransaction`. Hence, calling `success()` or `close()` on it has no effect whatsoever.

Consequently, everything you access in the child transactions, whilst the top-level one is open, is held in memory (heap) until the top-level transaction is finished. I know these are two different databases, but still, it's `ThreadLocal`.

I think you should attempt to close the top-level one each time you close the child one as well. See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually I do it every time child is closed. Also, I make a new object for each new query as a GraphDatabaseService. But initializing a new GraphDatabaseService for knowledge graph is not time affordable for me, if I have to do it.